# Google Chart with Decimal Number

Tags: php, ajax, google-visualization

I have a ajax function which gives the response like:

```
[{"lot_no":"Lot A","sent_weight":"20.8","received_weight"
:"19.3"},{"lot_no":"Lot B","sent_weight":"6.8","received_weight"
:"5.3"},{"lot_no":"Lot C","sent_weight":"7.8","received_weight"
:"10.3"}]
```

I want to draw the google function chart on basis of Lot no, sent weight and received weight but the problem is :
**Type mismatch. Value "20.8" does not match type number in column index 1**
How can i make a google function chart with these sort of response data

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.3.3, there's a [flag](http://php.net/json_encode) for auto-converting numbers (the options parameter was added in PHP 5.3.0):

```
$arr = array( 'row_id' => '1', 'name' => 'George' );
echo json_encode( $arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
// {"row_id":1,"name":"George"}
```

This will help you.

Comment: Did you mean while passing the response from the function to the ajax on call?

Comment: Yes, its just like the data you are returning from the server as ajax response

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax response is returning the string values in respective keys. Convert  the string into float value `example: parseFloat("10.33")`, this will return number format.